# Latent Profile Analysis (LPA) in R - distal outcomes or covariates

Tags: r, classification, latent-variable

I am conducting a latent profile analysis (LPA) in R and I'd like to examine the relationship between most likely class membership and some covariates (e.g., can I predict class membership from background characteristics, etc.)

I fit the model using mclust (4 classes, EEI configuration) but I can't figure out how to save class by subject ID. I pasted my code below. Let's suppose in data frame df, columns 1-7 are my LPA indicators and column 8 is SubjectID.

There is a similar issue discussed in this post but I am doing LPA (with continuous indicators) so I think poLCA doesn't apply: [How can you implement latent class analysis with distal outcomes in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396843/how-can-you-implement-latent-class-analysis-with-distal-outcomes-in-r)

```
##### Fit 4 class EEI model
mod_g4EEI <- Mclust(df[, 1:7], G = 4, modelNames = "EEI")

cprob_4EEI <- cbind(mod_g4EEI$z, mod_g4EEI$classification)
cprob_4EEI <- as.data.frame(cprob_4EEI)
colnames(cprob_4EEI) <- c("prob (class 1)", "prob (class 2)", "prob (class 3)", 
                          "prob (class 4)",
                          "class")
```

Comment: When posting code, it is better to provide a reproducible example where you have simulated data for `df` yourself.  This way, any reviewer can instantly run the code and understand your question better.

Comment: I wrote the answer you linked to.I argue it does apply. LPA and LCA differ only in the name and the exact likelihood function. The issue which makes distal covariates a problem in LCA is also present in LPA.